react native throws "cannot read property of null" error for a function inside a properly defined module
import BackgroundGeolocation from '@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation';

//inside a useffect hook
console.log(BackgroundGeolocation) 
// Does print out all the functions and the propities of the module including "configure": [Function configure], this is also called a line before the error"
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ // <-- THE PROBLEM --> "TypeError: Cannot read property of null" ????? 
  //my config
});
//

tried clearing cache, uninstalling/re installing, restarting expo go
couldnt find anything about this online. Also chat gpt didnt help much.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?
